# How can I install GNU Parallel alongside Moreutils on Ubuntu/Debian?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management

Can I make the package manager resolve the conflict e.g. by renaming the binary (*e.g. parallel → gparallel*) or installing to a different place (*e.g. /usr/ → /usr/local/* )?

Answer (score 20):

For *Ubuntu v17.04 ("Zesty Zapus")* and *Debian v9 ("Stretch")*, (*2017* or newer), or distros based upon those versions, please read [Bryan Larsen's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1253492/582419) **first**, which should be sufficient.

For versions from before *2017*, read on...

---

Use `dpkg` to *force* the install; **parallel** gets along nicely with **moreutils** -- it renames **moreutils**' `parallel` util to `parallel.moreutils`.  When the install is done both programs (*GNU* and *moreutils*) are available.

NB: if any *user* scripts call the old **moreutils** `parallel`, change those scripts to use the longer name.

Details:  Fetch **parallel** package (without installing or removing anything).  Then using `compgen`, (a `bash` internal command), find **parallel** package in archive.  If there's more than one, use the latest.  Force that package to install, despite conflicts.

```
apt-get --assume-yes --download-only install parallel &&
ls --sort=version $(compgen -f /var/cache/apt/archives/parallel) |
    tail -n 1 | xargs dpkg --force-conflicts -i
```

How to view the resulting diversions:

```
dpkg-divert --list 'par*'
```

Output:

```
diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/parallel.1.gz to  /usr/share/man/man1/parallel.moreutils.1.gz by parallel
diversion of /usr/bin/parallel to /usr/bin/parallel.moreutils by parallel
```

See how both binary executables are available:

```
compgen -c parallel | xargs which | xargs ls -l
```

Output:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 240814 Oct 31  2014 /usr/bin/parallel
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  10592 Jul 21  2015 /usr/bin/parallel.moreutils
```

Comment: Maybe not!  This _used_ to work OK, but on a Lubuntu box, everything installs, but _apt-get_ keeps wanting to get rid of one the parallels... probably needs another override.  More later...

Comment: ...except that `apt-get install` keeps complaining about the conflict, as you wrote earlier.

Comment: I edited `/var/lib/dpkg/status` to remove the conflict. Searched for "Conflicts: moreutils", deleted this line. Source: http://superuser.com/a/815371/99136. Seems to work now, but I fear an update of the "parallel" package will break things again.

Comment: Nope: `apt-get install` warns that `parallel` package won't be upgraded, but `apt-cache policy` doesn't show different versions, and even `apt-get dist-upgrade` won't touch the `parallel` package. So, upgrading `parallel` seems to be a process that has to be initiated consciously. Fine with me.

Comment: @krlmlr, that's a new one on me...  BTW, if you'd be so kind as to post the above trick here [Set apt-get options to tolerate harmless 'dpkg --force-conflicts' kludge?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281302/set-apt-get-options-to-tolerate-harmless-dpkg-force-conflicts-kludge), I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 10):

#### This conflict is solved in *Ubuntu 17.04* and *Debian Stretch*.

If you install *parallel* & *moreutils* you get the *GNU* `parallel` as `/usr/bin/parallel` and *moreutil*'s `parallel` as `/usr/bin/parallel.moreutils`.   If you only install *moreutils*, it provides `/usr/bin/parallel`.

If you're using an older version of *Ubuntu* or *Debian*, you could download and install the .deb's from a newer version: they install & work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the easiest route would be to install one of the packages normally (e.g. `parallel`) and just extract another one to the custom path:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libio-pty-perl libipc-run-perl
$ sudo apt-get download moreutils
$ dpkg -x moreutils_0.54-1_amd64.deb /tmp/moreutils
$ cd /tmp/moreutils/usr/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU parallels is just a perl script, so you could just copy it somewhere useful (e.g. /usr/local/bin/gnu-parallel).

(Just check the perl dependencies).